# Triggering an event in subform control in Access using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I wanted to trigger an after update event in the subform using vba from the parent form.

In the subform I have:

```
Private Sub USER_AfterUpdate()
  'After update code
End sub
```

The subforms name in my parent form is `subForm2`

So from my main form I am doing:

```
Call subForm2.Form.USER_AfterUpdate
```

However, I get

> Application-defined or object defined error

I wanted to target the last user field in my subform but I do not mind running an after update event on all of the user field in the sub form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either make the function *Public*:

```vb
Public Sub USER_AfterUpdate()
  'After update code
End Sub
```

or create a separate function to call:

```vb
Private Sub USER_AfterUpdate()
    UserAfterUpdate
End sub

Public Sub UserAfterUpdate()
  'After update code
End sub
```

and then call this (UserAfterUpdate) from the main form.

You may have to use the extended syntax:

[Call procedures in a subform or subreport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/controls/call-procedures-in-a-subform-or-subreport)

Comment: I chaged it to public but my code does not run anymore because it shows : "sub or function not defined" error

Comment: See extended answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use strong typing to reach to your subforms methods. I find this approach much more readable than the extended syntax proposed by Gustav.

Say your subform is named "Form_Subform", and included in a subform control called "subForm2". You could write:

```
Dim subform as Form_Subform
Set subform = Me.subForm2.Form
Call subform.USER_AfterUpdate
```

You will find that, after assigning to a strongly typed variable, intellisense will show you all the public subs and functions of your subform (which is not the case with `subform.Form`, as my best guess there is that it's seen as the parent class `Form` and not your `Form_Subform` implementation).